# Change Windows AD password from Linux

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, samba

Is there a way to change my Windows domain password from Linux?

Answer (score 22):

I've done this on OS X, the same command exist on linux.

According to this [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20150810201708/http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Using_smbpasswd_to_reset_Windows_domain_password.html). Looks like the way to avoid adding the username to smbpasswd file to use `smbpasswd -U <user> -r <IP address of DC>`

Comment: According to the [smbpasswd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smbpasswd), this won't do the right thing; the `-a` flag means "the username following should be added to the local smbpasswd file".  It's possible that the man page is incorrect; but I'm suspicious.

Comment: Thanks I checked the manpage and then checked google and changed the answer.

Comment: Error was : NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.  But if I use smbclient -L to try and list servers, I get a different error message that my password has expired, which implies that the password I'm typing is correct.

Comment: I get `NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT`. Is there a port that must be opened for this command to work?

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the same solution as `@JamesBarnett`, I've just created a script that also gets the domain controller IP too *(I never know what the IP is when I need to change my password)*.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="your.username"
DOMAIN="yourdomain.com"

smbpasswd -U $USER -r `nslookup _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.$DOMAIN | awk '{print $2;exit;}'`
```

Comment: The `nslookup` command will not work as given, because the ldap record is of DNS type SRV. You need to perform: `nslookup -type=SRV ...etc...` and filter it appropriately (it's more complicated than a simple awk), or  better yet: `$(dig SRV +noall +additional _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.$DOMAIN | awk '{print $5}')` replaces the entire nslookup between the backticks that you have, above.

Comment: @MikeS that command outputs multiple servers separated by whitespace, but I suspect that smbpasswd might want a single server.

Comment: @Trejkaz Yes, that's what I mean by "filter it appropriately". The DNS records are of type SRV, that's for starters. How you get the SRV records I have shown. Now, how you choose a domain controller, that part I'm not sure of.